# Why ARMA models works on assumption of uniformly sampled time series?

Tags: arima, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am dealing with irregularly spaced time series data. I have been reading papers how ARMA based approaches can be used for time series forecasting.

However, ARMA assumes uniformly sampled time series data. I want to understand the explanation behind this assumption that "ARMA models require uniformly sampled data."

Consider a discrete time series $ \mathbf{y} = [(t_1,y_1), (t_2,y_2),(t_3,y_3)....(t_k,y_k)...,(t_n,y_n)]$ with $|t_k - t_{k-1}| = c \,\, \forall k$. I have missing observation pairs at different time instants and the irregular-spaced time series looks like $ \mathbf{y} = [(t_1,y_1), (t_3,y_3),(t_4,y_4),(t_7,y_7), (t_8,y_8),(t_9,y_9),(t_{15},y_{15}),(t_{32},y_{32}),..,(t_n,y_n)]$. The problem is to predict $y$ p-step ahead at time instants $[t_{n+1},t_{n+2},....t_{n+p}]$. Currently, I am imputing values in between using linear interpolation and then trying to fit an arma(p,q) model the time series by maximising the likelihood. I want to understand if this is the right approach or i can directly use the  irregular time series to fit the arma model.

Some pointers/links for a specific read would also suffice.

Comment: I don't really get your concern. In the AR part you have sth like $x_t=x_{t-1}+x_{t-2}+x_{t-3}$ – from the very defining equation of a discrete ARMA process. If you have e.g. $x_{t-2}$ lacking, how do you want to predict $x_t$? Or differently: if $x_t$ is lacking in the actual observations, but you have $x_{t-1},x_{t-2},x_{t-3}$, you can use them to estimate $x_t$. This way you can fill in the missing data. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0841). For continuous data, there's CARMA; see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5978).

Comment: @corey979, sorry for the delay in response. I have edited the original question as per your response.